# SDL_BlitSurface doesn't draw to screen

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to simply create a window and blit an image to the screen but for some reason the image is not showing up and the screen remains white.  I've been using lazyfoo's tutorial for reference in order to figure this out.  I posted all my code below, hopefully it's readable enough.  Help would be appreciated as I've been stuck on this for an hour or two, thank you.

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_audio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>


// creates Load_surface function
SDL_Surface *loadSurface(std::string path) {
    SDL_Surface *loadedSurface = SDL_LoadBMP(path.c_str());
    if (loadedSurface == NULL) {
       printf("Unable to load image %s! SDL Error: %s\n", path.c_str(), 
         SDL_GetError());
    }
    return loadedSurface;

}



int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{


    // pointer variable for window
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Surface *surface = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *media = 
         loadSurface("C:\\Users\\nickl\\Desktop\\buttonpressed.bmp");


    // initialize and test for failure
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO) == -1) {

        return 1;
    }





    // create the window
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Ice Cream Boys Software",
        48,
        48,
        640,
        480,
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL
     );

    // safety check, see if window was created, otherwise throw an error
    if (window = NULL) {
        printf("Could not create window: %s", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        OutputDebugString(TEXT("Surface loaded.\n"));
        surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    }

    SDL_BlitSurface(media, NULL, surface, NULL);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

    /* ************************************** loop  **************************** */
    // bool to keep window open and event handler
    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event e;





    // loop to keep window open
    while (!quit) {
         while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
             if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                 quit = true;
            }
             else if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
                 OutputDebugString(TEXT("My output string.\n"));


             }

         }
     }

    /* ************************************************************************** */



    // close and destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    // quit
    SDL_Quit();






    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you pass in `0` for `flags` instead of `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL`?  `SDL_GetWindowSurface()` doesn't play well with OpenGL or the SDL_Renderer system.  Also, move the `SDL_LoadBMP()` to *after* `SDL_Init()`, doing it before does not give me warm fuzzies.  Did you verify that `surface` is non-NULL after the `SDL_GetWindowSurface()` call?

Comment: I did all of what you said.  Apparently `surface` is null even after running `SDL_GetWindowSurface()`.  Thanks!

Comment: The code has errors, `if (Window = NULL)`, you mean `Window == NULL`

Comment: Oh, >.<  Thanks.

Comment: Did that fix your problem?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the super late reply.